Can PE and GND be the same for HY2112 to Function?
If C1 is connected to GND instead of PE, will the HY2112 device fail to disconnect the battery?
My understanding is that HY2112 (similar to DW01A) measures cell current using R2 as a shunt. If OC for a given voltage (measured using VDD-VSS) or OV, it will open M1 or M2 respectively. This should disconnect the negative terminal of the cell from PB-.
However, if you use GND instead of PE on C1, will this fail to disconnect the cell?

Datasheet: https://www.hycontek.com/wp-content/uploads/DS-HY2112_EN.pdf
Edit:
My current application looks something like below (protected- = gnd = C19) but i don't think this works because M1 M2 opening still leave batt- connected to common ground. PB+ is also still connected to the load so this won't work. What should i do to fix this? Do i need to add PE to my design to separate to cell from common ground? Can i use M1/M2 to open PB+ from the load?

Edit2:
This screenshot shows how i connect the load on the battery. Because the filter (?) cap is connected to the same ground, i think it can still power the load even when m1 and m2 are open


Your schematic is incorrect.
There is no direct connection between PB- and ground.
That connection is made only when the mosfets are conducting.


I thought that M1 and M2 are closed during nominal operation of the cell. The issue is that the right ground always connects the battery to common ground even if m1/m2 are open.

Yes, M1 opens on over-discharge and M2 on over-charge. In both the cases, PB- is disconnected from ground. Could you please explain what you mean by 'However, if you use GND instead of PE on C1, will this fail to disconnect the cell?' ?

i edited the original post to show which ground point is still connected even when M1 M2 are open. The data sheet recommends to use PE instead of ground here but i'm trying to see if that's required.

There appears to be some confusion. Opening M1 / M2 will disconnect  PB- from battery negative.

I don't think it will if protected- and batt- are both at ground right?

Protected- is at ground only when the mosfets are closed - not otherwise !

i added another screenshot to show how the load is connected. Note that the load doesn't use protected-. It uses common ground.

The very purpose of the battery protection circuit is defeated if you connect the load between battery positive and negative! PB+ and PB- are the designated load terminals.

That's what i was thinking. So i need another ground to connect the cap to

You just need to disconnect PB- from battery negative (what you refer to as ground).
